# Why didn't the Riverworld Ethicals initially know which was Burton's slot in the Resurrection Bubble?

Tags: riverworld

When the Ethicals finally captured Burton they said they'd only identified his 'slot' in the Resurrection Bubble due to his high count of 777 resurrections leading them to investigate that slot.  But right at the start of the book when he woke up in the chamber and was put back to sleep, surely the Ethicals would have made a note of which slot he was in for further investigation?

Comment: Why would they do that?  Maybe people waking up wasn't that uncommon?